# Free open source C/C++ library to solve 2d Poisson equation using the finite difference method

Tags: finite-difference, c

I have been writing some code in C for [particle-in-cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle-in-cell) simulation.
One of the steps of the PIC algorithm requires to solve (numerically) Poisson's equation

$$
\Delta \varphi = - 4 \pi \rho.
$$

Initially I want to limit the program to 2d case ( instead of 3d ) and use the finite difference method ( instead of finite elements ).

Much to my surprise, I was not able to find any free open source C library for this task ( i.e. to solve 2d Poisson's equation using the finite difference method ).
The only thing I've found is a FISHPACK - collection of FORTRAN77 routines, part of a famous SLATEC library.

I'm fine with fortran, but a call to a fortran routine from C requires some unnecessary array transformations and "native" C solution seems more convenient. 
Another reason I hesitate to use FISHPACK is that it uses single precision floats with implicit type declaration. 
Using the gcc '-fdefault-real-8' flag I was able to convert it to double precision, but I'm not sure whether or not everything still works correctly after this.

So, my question is: are there any free ( as in freedom ) C/C++ libraries to solve 2d Poisson equation using the finite difference method?
And since I do intend to switch to 3d and finite elements, advices on C library for this purpose are also welcome.

Comment: It looks like you want to solve for the gravity potential. This typically involves solving in all of ${\mathbb R}^3$, which presents a significant complication of your task. Is this so?

Comment: No, I want to do a plasma simulation where electromagnetic interaction is a primary force and gravity is typically neglected. The simulation domain is finite, not the whole  ${\mathbb R}^3$. Besides, I want to start from 2D domain and later switch to 3D.

Comment: Is uniform orthogonal grid sufficient for you? In that case I am preparing to release such a library. Which is a single purpose thing that could be used instead of FISHPACK for people that do not want to use large frameworks. Fortran 2008 with C bindings...

Comment: Yes, uniform orthogonal grid is currently sufficient. Please, do post a link here when you make a release.

Comment: [PoisFFT](https://github.com/LadaF/PoisFFT) by @VladimirF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2-D Poisson by finite differences looks to be a few examples in PETSc (KSP: ex29, ex32, ex50). I'd probably use a nonlinear solver (SNES) or time-stepper (TS) in PETSc anyway for the added flexibility. 2-D Poisson via finite differences is probably an example in other packages (for instance, probably Trilinos). I know it's an example given in Using MPI.

There are many free C/C++ libraries to solve Poisson via finite elements. You could try PETSc again, deal.II, DUNE, FEniCS, [any other library in this list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_element_software_packages), or (probably) Trilinos. Using a library like deal.II or FEniCS, it looks to be relatively easy to change the dimensionality of a code (i.e., go from 2-D to 3-D), so you might consider writing a 2-D finite element code to start, and then converting it to 3-D.

Comment: Yes, deal.II (http://www.dealii.org/) has several examples solving the Poisson equation in 2d, 3d, with uniform or adaptive meshes, and also on a few 10,000 processors if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the references to the examples. I'll take a closer look at PETSc.